# How to get colors from colors.xml in Android

Tags: android, xml, colors

I have declared colours in `color.xml` file but unfortunately unable to get those colours while setting the colour attribute to textview.

Color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="dark_snuff">#2d3037</color>  
   <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
   <color name="dark_gray">#A9A9A9</color> 
</resources>
```

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
            android:background="@android:Color/dark_snuff"/>//error part

        </LinearLayout>
```

Error:

`error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@android:Color/
 dark_snuff').`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write `@color/dark_snuff`. That should do it!

EDIT as @Machinarius said, the prefix `android` refers to the namespace of Android's built-in colors, whereas you want colors from your own project. Also, in resource identifiers, everything must be lower case, so an uppercase `Color` wouldn't work, even if the resource you were trying to access existed in the appropriate namespace.

Comment: As for why that would of work? android: prefixed identifiers are for android-bundled resources, not your project's ones.

Comment: @Machinarius thanks for that extra bit of info, i should have included that.

Answer (score 2):

`@android:color/...` is used to get a resource color from Android library. Whereas `@color/...` is used to get the resource color from the `colors.xml` file (with an "`s`" at the end and without caps) into the app.

```
android:background="@color/dark_snuff"
```

should be the solution to get your own `color` items. However, if you want to use Android resources color, it's as follows:

```
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

without caps. And you can find all of them in the [Resources Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
@android:Color/dark_snuff refers to the default built-in colors available in android. So plase use android:background="@color/dark_snuff" which WILL do the trick.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a set of styles in your xml (regularly in res/values/styles.xml)

```
<color name="gray">#eaeaea</color>
<color name="titlebackgroundcolor">#00abd7</color>
<color name="titlecolor">#666666</color>
```

In the layout files you can call to the colors or styles:

```
android:textColor="@color/titlecolor"
```

Answer (score 1):

The first of all u should not save the file name with Caps (Capital letters) and if it is your application res folder which you are calling should be `@color/dark_snuff` not like `@android:Color/dark_snuff`